# What are some ways to implement a show more/less with my unordered list

Tags: angularjs

I have a section in my AngularJS web page that contains an unordered list. Sometimes the list can be very long and I would like to implement a "show more/less" feature defaulting to show less. Show top 3 if in show less mode.

Here is the AngularJS snippet:

```
<p><i>Key Responsibilities</i></p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contribution in emp.contributions">{{contribution}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `track by $index` and an `ng-if` directive on `$index` variable and use a local variable in order to put limit on your list.

```
<p><i>Key Responsibilities</i></p>
<ul ng-init="limit = 4">
   <li ng-repeat="contribution in emp.contributions track by $index" ng-if="$index < limit">
{{contribution}}
   </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="limit = limit + 4">Show More</button>
<button ng-click="limit = limit - 4">Show Less</button>
```

Comment: So that works for me, but let me ask a question. For the button click, I combined the Show More/Less into one button.I have expressions on 3 attributes which kinda mangles the html. And I thought the purpose of AngularJS was to have clean markup. Is there a way to move all this to the controller? `<input id="Button1" class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="rows=rows===limit?emp.contributions.length:limit;" value="Show {{rows<=limit?'More':'Less'}}" ng-show="emp.contributions.length>limit" />`

Comment: It actually is possible to maintain your markup using different (and somehow complex conditions). However, if I were you I would keep two buttons remain for sustainability. maybe some day I want to do some pagination from server side so I could easily seperate functions between more and less because clicking on Less will cause me some frontend work blah blah! But everything in two curly braces `{{}}` is possible in AngularJS! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter:

```
<p><i>Key Responsibilities</i></p>
<ul ng-init="limit = 4">
  <li ng-repeat="contribution in emp.contributions | limitTo:limit">{{contribution}}</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="limit = limit + 4">Show More</button>
<button ng-click="limit = limit - 4">Show Less</button>
```

Here's maybe a slightly better solution which moves most of the logic into a controller: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYhTEVJZcLonMqp7?open=lib%2Fscript.js).